# have_posts arguments with multiple categories required

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to run a Wordpress have_posts() query to return a list of items that match ALL categories listed in the array $all_cats (plus a couple of ACF fields, but that is working).

However the result returns all products matching any of the categories.  I haven't been able to direct the query to look at the categories as an AND instead of an OR for the categories and there may not always be the same number of categories from item to item:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 500,
    'product_cat'    => $all_cats, //only return products that fall into ALL categories
    'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'style',
        'value'     => $rug_style,
        'compare'   => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'rug_color',
        'value'     => $rug_color,
        'compare'   => '=',
    ),
),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the standard WordPress [have_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/) loop accepts arguments. You're going to have to look into a custom query with [WP_Query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) or [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/). You'll be able to pass in all those arguments and should filter the results as you're expecting.

I tried to find other links to back up my answer because I'm certainly no WP expert, but since it doesn't explicitly say that it **can** accept args, then I assume it implies that it **can't**.